# how to use selector to selector in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-template

[image]> home.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: [
        'home.scss'
    ] 
})
```

> //home.component.html

```
<jhi-download></jhi-download>
<jhi-contact></jhi-contact>
.....
<h3 jhiTranslate="global.title">TEST</h3>  [working]  jhiTranslate: true
```

> //contact.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-contact',
    templateUrl: './contact.component.html'
})
```

> //contact.component.html

```
<h3 jhiTranslate="global.title">TEST</h3>  [not working] jhiTranslate: false
```

Although it works in the home component, it does not work when I call it from within. For example, no translations work in

```
 <jhi-download></jhi-download>
  <jhi-contact></jhi-contact>
```

How would you suggest a solution?

Comment: from within means ?

Comment: i want to use in  contact.component.html <h3 jhiTranslate="global.title">TEST</h3>  [not working] jhiTranslate: false

Comment: where is this global.title variable in the same ts file

Comment: global.title is  i18n/tr - en /global.json  global is auto  export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private jhiLanguageService: JhiLanguageService
    ) {
        this.jhiLanguageService.setLocations(['global', 'address']);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}

Comment: global.title should be a variable corresponding to the ts file if this is coming from a global json file try and get this value from a service

Comment: how i can it? it is : constructor( private jhiLanguageService: JhiLanguageService ) { this.jhiLanguageService.setLocations(['global', 'address']); } ngOnInit() { } }

Comment: you have a variable in service that points to the value of the global variable and on onInit you get it from the service and then use it in the template